# c# creating then doing stuff to a file

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am trying to create a small program which allows the user to create/open a file, then read/write to it. So far the file seems to only exist after I quit the program, I get opening errors when I try to access it, but if I rerun the program it says the file is in use elsewhere... Ideas?
I'm using FileStream.Create to make the file then StreamReader/Writer to change it. 
File Creation:

```
if (File.Exists( @path ))
   {
      Console.WriteLine( "Sorry, the path {0} already exists.\n", path );
   }
   else
   {
       FileStream file;
       try
       {
          file = File.Create( path );
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          Console.WriteLine( "EXCEPTION HAS BEEN THROWN:\n " + ex + "\n" );
       }
}
```

File reading:

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader( @path ))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine( line );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Can you be a bit more specific and show some code?

Comment: Are you disposing your FileStream? If not - from the info you provided - it seems like a possible reason for your problems. But please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you close and dispose `StreamReaders` and `StreamWriters` after using them? Cause most "file is in use elsewhere" problems are because of that.
And if `FileStream.Create()` does not work, try to use `File.Create()` or `File.CreateText()` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by close and dispose of? 
And the file is in use elsewhere only occurs when I create the file immediately quit then restart the program...

Comment: Closing and disposing means, that you always have to call StreamReader.Close() and StreamReader.Dispose() methods after using them, or the Stream stays open even after you close your app.

Comment: Even when doing the using StreamReader? 
I pulled the code pretty much directly from microsofts example and they never close it...

Comment: Well, if you write your code with a "using", you don't realy have to close and dispose it to make it work, but I used to leave that "using" and declare my StreamReaders and StreamWriters simply without that, then call the Close() and Dispose() methods after using them. This way always works for me. Try it and if they don't work, the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Yea, I tried that and it still doesn't work... Do I have to close the FileStream?
I'm used to Python where you can just store the file as a string/list. Can you do something like that in c#?

Comment: Since I wasn't sure about this, cause I'm not used to work with FileStreams in my apps, I quickly read after it, and found this page on msdn [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). Read the remarks, it sais you always have to dispose your Filestream object after using.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! That's incredibly useful to me